# Loading multiple BigQuery Tables into Spark\HadoopRDD

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

Is there a way to include multiple tables in the input parameter when defining a BigQuery data import into HadoopRDD?

Here's my basic script.  How can I provide a list of tables rather than just *table_20160615*?

```
import json
import pprint
import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

# Use the Google Cloud Storage bucket for temporary BigQuery export data used
# by the InputFormat. This assumes the Google Cloud Storage connector for
# Hadoop is configured.
bucket = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
project = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory = 'gs://{}/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input'.format(bucket)

conf = {
    # Input Parameters
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'my_dataset',
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'table_20160615',
}

# Load data in from BigQuery.
table_data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)

pprint.pprint(table_data.take(10))
```

I've found that wildcards work, so I could use 'table_201606*' but it's not very precise.  I only want a select date range.

Alternative solutions I have are to create a union table in BigQuery or to extract the tables first as files and then use the textFile import method.  I would like to avoid the extra steps if possible.

Thank you!